# What are the actual script engines (apart from V8) wrapped by ClearScript?

Tags: javascript

*What are the actual script engines (apart from V8) wrapped by ClearScript?*
e.g. Chakra or the one go with WSH?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the website:

> Google's V8, Microsoft's JScript and VBScript

https://clearscript.codeplex.com/